# Speeding up query execution in MySql

Tags: mysql, performance

I am trying to execute this query in MySql:

```
SELECT areamaster.areaname, 
       builtydetails.builtycode, 
       builtydetails.builtyno, 
       builtydetails.builtydate, 
       builtydetails.pvtmarks, 
       areamaster_to.areaname, 
       stockview.pkgs, 
       stockview.state, 
       areamaster_from.areaname, 
       builtydetails.actualweight, 
       builtydetails.chargedweight, 
       consigner.customername, 
       consignee.customername, 
       stockview.calc, 
       stockview.stockdate 
FROM   (((((designpl_snps.stockview stockview 
            INNER JOIN designpl_snps.areamaster areamaster 
                    ON stockview.location = areamaster.areacode) 
           INNER JOIN designpl_snps.builtydetails builtydetails 
                   ON stockview.builtycode = builtydetails.builtycode) 
          INNER JOIN designpl_snps.areamaster areamaster_to 
                  ON builtydetails.toloc = areamaster_to.areacode) 
         INNER JOIN designpl_snps.areamaster areamaster_from 
                 ON builtydetails.fromloc = areamaster_from.areacode) 
        INNER JOIN designpl_snps.customermaster consigner 
                ON builtydetails.customercode = consigner.customercode) 
       INNER JOIN designpl_snps.customermaster consignee 
               ON builtydetails.customercode_consignee = consignee.customercode 
ORDER  BY areamaster.areaname, 
          builtydetails.builtycode
```

but this is taking intolerably long to execute.What are the ways and tricks using which this or any other mysql query may work faster?

Comment: using indexs on your join and order by columns

Comment: You are not filtering the data, so this query is presumably returning a lot of data.  How much data is being returned?  The performance issue may simply be due to the volume of data your query returns.

Comment: Use EXPLAIN on this query and post the results to see what indexes are being used. But without anything to narrow down the returned rows if there is a large  amount of data this SQL will be slow.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL it isn't an easy job. I don't know a query analyzing tool like in MSSQL. Maybe you can try it with mtop. There are another good thread about this topic: [Best MySQL performance tuning tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/362223/best-mysql-performance-tuning-tool)

Try to put your query in a VIEW. Because mysql cache the query an the result of it. That means, the query take longer for the first time, afterwards it speed it up, because the server don't need to execute the whole query.

Another option is the EXPLAIN command, see here: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/

I hope it helps

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

(1) : You should use indexes on your join and order by columns

(2) : Try to use `where` instead of `inner join`. Where clause will bring faster result that `inner join`.

```
SELECT areamaster.areaname, 
       builtydetails.builtycode, 
       builtydetails.builtyno, 
       builtydetails.builtydate, 
       builtydetails.pvtmarks, 
       areamaster_to.areaname, 
       stockview.pkgs, 
       stockview.state, 
       areamaster_from.areaname, 
       builtydetails.actualweight, 
       builtydetails.chargedweight, 
       consigner.customername, 
       consignee.customername, 
       stockview.calc, 
       stockview.stockdate 
FROM   designpl_snps.stockview stockview ,
       designpl_snps.areamaster areamaster ,
       designpl_snps.builtydetails builtydetails ,
       designpl_snps.areamaster areamaster_to ,
       designpl_snps.areamaster areamaster_from ,
       designpl_snps.customermaster consigner ,
       designpl_snps.customermaster consignee 

 WHERE

  stockview.location = areamaster.areacode and 
  stockview.builtycode =   builtydetails.builtycode and 
  builtydetails.toloc = areamaster_to.areacode and 
  builtydetails.fromloc = areamaster_from.areacode and 
  builtydetails.customercode = consigner.customercode and  
  builtydetails.customercode_consignee = consignee.customercode 

ORDER  BY areamaster.areaname, 
          builtydetails.builtycode
```

Comment: This advice is inaccurate.  DO NOT USE IMPLICIT JOINs IN THE WHERE CLAUSE; USE EXPLICIT JOIN SYNTAX.  This seems like an important enough principle to put in all-caps.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can you give an example of using explicit join in mysql ?

Comment: . . The original query in the question was written correctly.